# E-Mail body new line for each string

Tags: powershell

I have an array called `$faultypath` which contains filepath-strings.

To send them via `Send-Mailmessage` I have to merge them into a single string:

```
$bdy = $faultypath | Out-String
```

I send my E-Mail as HTML (`-BodyAsHtml`) is there a trick I can use to get every filepath in my `$bdy` on a new line? Right now they're on the same line in the E-Mail.

```
if($faultypath) {
    $utf8 = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding
    $bdy = $faultypath | Out-String
    Send-MailMessage -From gdfgdfg `
                     -To dgdfgfdg `
                     -SmtpServer dgfgdfg  `
                     -Subject "LogDeleter: Log-Pfad nicht gefunden" `
                     -Body "LogDeleter.ps1 konnte folgende Pfade nicht überprüfen:<br /><br />$bdy<br /><br />bitte aus LogDelete.ps1 löschen." `
                     -BodyAsHtml `
                     -Encoding $utf8
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-join` to combine the paths with a `<br />`. Then you have each path separated by a new line and don't need the `Out-String` anymore:

```
$bdy = $faultypath -join '<br />'
```